# 時系列データで連続する値をグルーピングするSQL

Tags: sql

```
I,T,V
A,1,0
A,2,0
A,3,1
A,4,1
A,5,1
A,6,0
A,7,1
A,8,1
A,9,0
A,10,0
```

こんなデータがあった時以下のようなデータをSQLで生成するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

①
Iのグルーピング,V=1が連続するグループの数
A,2

②
I毎のVが1が連続するグループのIDのグルーピング,I毎のV=1が連続するグループの最初のT,I毎のV=1が連続するグループの最後のT
A3,3,5
A7,7,8

Answer (score 1):

この回答ではテーブル名を`X`とします。

> Iのグルーピング,V=1が連続するグループの数

値が連続するものをグループ化し、そのグループ数の数える方法ですが、`T`と`T+1`を比較し存在しない場合をグループの先頭を検出できます。

```
SELECT T
FROM X
WHERE T NOT IN (SELECT T+1 FROM X)
```

これをベースに、グループ化や条件を付けていけば組み立てることができます。最終的にはこんな感じでしょうか。

```
SELECT I, COUNT(*)
FROM X AS X1
WHERE V=1 AND T NOT IN (SELECT T+1 FROM X AS X2 WHERE V=1 AND X1.I=X2.I)
GROUP BY I
```

> I毎のVが1が連続するグループのIDのグルーピング,I毎のV=1が連続するグループの最初のT,I毎のV=1が連続するグループの最後のT

こちらは自己回答されているように`ROW_NUMBER()`等が必要になってきます。

Comment: なるほど。グループのTを１ずらした配列に含まれない＝先頭というロジックですね。勉強になりました！

Answer (score 0):

英語版で参考になる質問を見つけて自己解決しました。

[Grouping contiguous table data - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48411640)

```sql
WITH step1 AS(
SELECT
I,T,V,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY I,T) AS A,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I,V ORDER BY T) AS B
FROM table
ORDER BY
I,T ),
step2 AS(
SELECT
I,T,V,A,B,
A - B AS RN
FROM STEP1
ORDER BY I,T ),
step3 AS(
SELECT
I,
CONCAT(I,MIN(T)) AS I_T1,
MIN(T) T1,
MAX(T) T2,
V
FROM
step2
GROUP BY I,V,RN
ORDER BY T1 )
--①
--SELECT I,V,count(V) count_V FROM step3 Group by I,V
--②
SELECT * FROM step3 WHERE V =1
```